# Linking web page domains

Tags: url, dns, web

So I have brought 2 domain names for my new business one is .org through Google and the other is .co from Pop! is there any way that I can link the two so if someone was to go to the .org page they would be automatically directed to the .co url? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answers guys, I'm at the really basic stage with tech so is their a simpler explanation to do this? Thanks Heaps :)

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are a couple ways, but easiest would be to configure your domain forwarding.  I assume you're using google domains?  I wish I could help more, but I don't have an invite to google domains, so I can't provide links to their docs...there seems to be a [link right off their splash page](https://domains.google.com/about/features.html), though.

Answer (score 0):

You could add meta tags to your page for redirection (example: meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://yourdomain.com/") , but since you mentioned using Google domains, try this out https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141?hl=en